image gallery using magnific-popup always popup first one, not the one selected when clicked
I'm using JQUERY and Magnific Popup in a django project. When I clicked on any image in the gallery, it always popup the first image instead of the one selected. This is my current code:
Here is the django template
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
{% for image in images %}
  <div class="image">
    <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ dir }}/{{ image }}">
      {% thumbnail MEDIA_ROOT|add:"images/"|add:dir|add:"/"|add:image 300x300 crop="smart" as im %}
      <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ dir }}/{{ image }}" class="image-link">
        <img src="{{ im.url }}">
      </a>
    </a>
    <div class="info">
      <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ dir }}/{{ image }} " class="title" >
        {{ dir }}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}

Here is the javascript and magnific popup
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()  { 
   $(document).on('click', '.image-link',function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
           type: 'image',
           closeOnContentClick: true,
           closeBtnInside: true,
           midClick: true,
           mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
           gallery: {
               enabled: true,
               navigateByImgClick: true,
               preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
           },
           image: {
             verticalFit: true,
           },
           zoom: {
             enabled: true
           },
           callbacks: {
              beforeOpen: function() {

              }
            },     
       }).magnificPopup('open');
   });
  });
 </script>


Add scroll event to initialize magnific popup for all pages.
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()  { 
    function initializeMagnificPopup() {
       $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
           type: 'image',
           closeOnContentClick: true,
           closeBtnInside: true,
           midClick: true,
           mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
           gallery: {
               enabled: true,
               navigateByImgClick: true,
               preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
           },
           image: {
             verticalFit: true,
           },
           zoom: {
             enabled: true
           },
           callbacks: {
              open: function() {
                  jQuery('body').addClass('magnificpopupnoscroll');
              },
              close: function() {
                  jQuery('body').removeClass('magnificpopupnoscroll');
              }   
          }, 
        });
      }
    // Initialize Magnific Popup when document is ready
    initializeMagnificPopup();

    // Reinitialize Magnific Popup on window scroll
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      initializeMagnificPopup();
    });

       // Click event handler for image links (No need to initialize Magnific Popup here)
    $(document).on('click', '.image-link', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      // Magnific Popup is already initialized, so no need to call it here
    });
  });
 </script>


I think the issue is that you are initializing Magnific Popup for every image link clicked, which would cause it to always open the first image in the gallery.
Try adjusting your JavaScript code like this:
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()  { 
    // Initialize Magnific Popup
    $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      closeBtnInside: true,
      midClick: true,
      mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
      gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
      },
      image: {
        verticalFit: true,
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true
      },
      callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {

        }
      },     
    });

    // Click event handler for image links (No need to initialize Magnific Popup here)
    $(document).on('click', '.image-link', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      // Magnific Popup is already initialized, so no need to call it here
    });
  });
</script>

Hope that solves it :)

Sorry Michael, it only works on 8 images. Nothing happens when i click on the ninth images, or further down.

And there is infinite scrolling call where are images available.

I figured out that I need to add scroll event to initialize magnific popup to enable all pages works . Otherwise only the 1st page works. Change the javascript like below:

